# Input dialog box in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was trying to call input Dialog on a fragment which has a button (for simplicity) and dialog box has an Edittext field to enter the text like this :

```
public class CreateDayFragment extends Fragment {

public CreateDayFragment(){
}
private Button button;![enter image description here][1]
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.createday_main, container, false);
    button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.createDayButton); 
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showInputDialog();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
protected void showInputDialog() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(CreateDayFragment.this.getActivity());
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.createday_dialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            CreateDayFragment.this.getActivity());
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView
            .findViewById(R.id.lectureDetailsEditText);
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"OK CLICKED",1000).show();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}
}
```

But this is not working .Please help as am not able to find out issues with this.

> 11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568): Process: com.example.loginphase, PID: 10568
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at com.example.loginphase.CreateDayFragment.onCreateView(CreateDayFragment.java:26)
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
>   11-04 08:43:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(10568):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Not working means..what ?? are you getting any error..explain in a clear manner..that will help here to answer your question properly .

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy Its crashing during Runtime.

Comment: When it crashes ....show me the logs

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy I posted the log

Comment: Can you tell me what is the code at thei line : CreateDayFragment.java:26

Comment: Perhaps you need https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-dialogfragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code

```
 button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.createDayButton);
```

like this

```
 button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.createDayButton);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Dialog instead of AlertDialog for this:

```
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        final EditText edittext = (EditText) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        Button button = (Button) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
```

Comment: I want to open dialog box on click of button

Comment: Yes, that is a "dialog box", you can use that in your showInputDialog();